# Reading from a file and converting to a float in Python

Tags: python

I would like to open a .txt file for reading and writing, save the contents to a variable and then convert that variable to type float. When converting the str type variable into type float I receive a ValueError: `could not convert string to float: ''`

```
file = open("my_file.txt", "r+")
value = file.read()
float_value = float(value)
```

My understanding is that if .txt is empty I will receive the error. If .txt contains a number and "r" is used no error appears. However I would like to read and write to the file and if I use w+ or r+ it automatically wipes the .txt thus not allowing for the conversion.

**How can I open the file for reading and writing so that it does not wipe the content of .txt?**

I found this problem in a similar thread and tried the following solution, but it does not work for me.

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.seek(0)
    value = file.read()
    float_value = float(value)
```

UPDATE:

I temporarily solved the issue by starting with 0 in .txt and then:

1. Opening the file in 'r'
2. Storing the value in a variable
3. Converting the stored str value into a float
4. Closing the file
5. Opening the file again, but this time as 'w' (.txt gets wiped, but my value is already stored in a float variable)
6. Performing any calculations to the float variable.
7. Converting the new value to a str type.
8. Writing the new value as str to .txt

I was hoping that r+ or w+ will allow me to perform these actions without having to open and close the file twice. I will make a second update if I find a solution that is simpler to implement.

Here is the temporary solution:

```
file = open("my_file.txt", "r")
value = file.read()
float_value = float(value)
file.close()

new_number = 5.5

file = open("my_file.txt", "w")
new_value = float_value + new_number
str_value = str(new_value)
file.write(str_value)
file.close()
```

UPDATE2:

I received a working solution, it is marked in the comments below.

Comment: Have you tried `'a'` instead of `'w'`?

Comment: @רועי אבידן From what I read 'a' is used for appending to a file. I would like to read and write so that the value in the file changes instead of appending a new value.

Comment: If you are reading the entire file as a single float, how to you want to append to the file without making it invalid the next time you try to read it? If the new file has a different format (multiple floats insead of just one) it might make sense to use a different file name.

Comment: @SPersonDPerson Check out my solution

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for the answer. I'm not trying to append to the file like you said. I simply want to read the contents of .txt which is the number 0. Then I would like to do something simple like contents of .txt as float + 10. The end result I expect to be 10.0.

Comment: @SPersonDPerson Please check my edited solution. You will get your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final solution:

You can minimize the code lines:

```
file = open("fileName.txt", "r+")
value = file.readlines()
for i in value:
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(str(float(i)+value you want to add))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution seems to work in your example, but it doesn't in my. The .txt file contains only 0. As I open the file and read its value I would later like to add to the original value. Your solution seems to append instead of add and replace. For example the value is 0, I then add 10, with your solution .txt returns 010 instead of 10.

Comment: @SPersonDPerson You will get the output by above solution. Try it and let me know

Comment: Thank you! This indeed works as intended, I marked your answer. Could you explain to me the logic behind file.write(str(float(i) + value))? Or point me to some docs that I could read please.

Comment: @SPersonDPerson In file.write() we can only pass string. So I converted it into string.  When you try to pass int or float it will throw the following error:- ```TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int```

Comment: Thank you again, that makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

To begin with, if you don't want to wipe the content of the file, you have to open it with the append mode.

```
with open("myfile.txt", "ra") as myfile:
```

Secondly, the error  you get is because you you can not convert every string to float.
If the text you try to convert is not a valid number, the error will be raised.
In this case, you have to handle it your self.

for example, if we assume that every line has 1 character, you could add in a loop the following logic

```
try:
    char_from_file = myfile.read()
    float_value = float(char_from_file)
    floats.append(float_value)
except ValueError: # char is is not a number
    pass
```